# Matrix rotation towards another matrix

Tags: android, matrix, opengl-es, transformation

I have two 4x4 rotation matrices M and N. M is describing my current object attitude in space, and N is a desired object attitude. Now I would like to rotate M matrix towards N, so the object will slowly rotate towards desired position in following iterations. Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: Matrices can't be interpolated directly. It would be better to store start angle and end angle, interpolate between them and then create the matrix. Quaternions might also be a suitable.

Comment: Android offers the SensorManager.getAngleChange(); method. It looks very promissing, but I do not know how could it be applied here

Answer (score 0):

If these matrices are not strange which should be the case describing "rotation matrices" you should do this by interpolating their base vectors in polar system.

To examine we want to convert top-left 3x3 matrix to 3 vectors defined by angles and distance. Once this is done you should do a linear interpolation on angles and distances for that top-left 3x3 part while the rest should have a direct cartesian interpolation. From angles and distances you can then convert back to cartesian coordinates.

Naturally there is still work internally like choosing which way to rotate (using closest) and checking there are no edge cases where one base vector rotates into different direction then the other...

I managed to successfully do this in 2D system which is a bit easier but should be no different in 3D.

To note a cartesian interpolation works fairly fine as long as angles are relatively small (<10 degrees to guess) which is most likely not your case at all.